# Flutter's WidgetTester.pumpAndSettle() does not wait for rendering finished?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, flutter, dart, widget

I have a `StatefulWidget` which state renders different `Widget` depending on loading state (Loading -> Loaded/Error):

```
// widget
class ListNotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/listNotes';
  static navigateTo(BuildContext context, [bool cleanStack = true]) =>
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, route, (_) => !cleanStack);

  final String title;
  final ListNotesUseCase _useCase;
  final VoidCallback _addNoteCallback;
  ListNotesScreen(this._useCase, this._addNoteCallback, {Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListNotesScreenState createState() => _ListNotesScreenState();
}

// state
class _ListNotesScreenState extends State<ListNotesScreen> {
  ListNotesLoadState _state;

  Future<ListNotesResponse> _fetchNotes() async {
    return widget._useCase.listNotes();
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadNotes();
  }

  _loadNotes() {
    setState(() {
      _state = ListNotesLoadingState();
    });

    _fetchNotes().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        _state = ListNotesLoadedState(response.notes);
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      setState(() {
        _state = ListNotesLoadErrorState(error);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Notes list'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: widget._addNoteCallback),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.refresh), onPressed: () => _loadNotes())
      ],
    ),
    body: _state.getWidget());
}

// loading states
// State:
@sealed
abstract class ListNotesLoadState {
  Widget getWidget();
}

// Loading
class ListNotesLoadingState extends ListNotesLoadState {
  @override
  Widget getWidget() => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(value: null));
}

// Loaded
class ListNotesLoadedState extends ListNotesLoadState {
  final List<Note> _notes;
  ListNotesLoadedState(this._notes);

  @override
  Widget getWidget() => ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (_, int index) => NoteItemWidget(this._notes[index]),
    itemCount: this._notes.length,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0));
}
```

Here is the test for the widget:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Notes list is shown', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final title1 = 'Title1';
    final title2 = 'Title2';
    final body1 = 'Body1';
    final body2 = 'Body2';
    var notes = [
      Note('1', title1, body1),
      Note('2', title2, body2),
    ];
    final listUseCase = TestListNotesInteractor(notes);
    final widget = ListNotesScreen(listUseCase, null, title: 'List notes');
    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.text('someInvalidString'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text(title1), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text(title2), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text(body1), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text(body2), findsOneWidget);

    // TODO: fix the test (tested manually and it works)
  });
}
```

So widget tester is expected to wait until the state it set to loading in `initState()`, then `_loadNotes` moves it to `ListNotesLoadedState` and `ListNotesLoadedState.getWidget()` to return `ListView` with expected string (`NoteItemWidget` root and few `Text` with expected string).

However the test fails. What's the reason (i was able to use test interactors in the app and visually see expected texts)? How can i analyze the actual Widgets tree on test failure?

I tend to think that WidgetTester did not wait for `Future` to be completed (though it's expected to be mocked and be sync behind the scenes, please correct me).

One can find the [project on Github](https://github.com/4ntoine/NotesClientApp/tree/issue-6-flutter/app-flutter/lib) (make sure to call `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` to generate json de-/serialize code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason: `MaterialApp` (or probably any app) should be the root of widgets tree!

```
final widget = MaterialApp(home: ListNotesScreen(interactor, null)); // succeeds
```

instead of:

```
final widget = ListNotesScreen(interactor, null); // fails
```

Also i've removed unused `title` property so the test code is a bit different form what i used originally:

```
final widget = ListNotesScreen(listUseCase, null, title: 'List notes');
```

It's not mentioned in [the docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/introduction) (is it the reason actually?) though the test code has it. Please let me know if i miss something.

Comment: Same problem here, although I'm using MaterialApp as the root. To be precise, the hierarchy is Multprovider -> Consumer -> MaterialApp. This hierarchy is used because I have an I18nProvider in Multiprovider and it is listened by the Consumer, which updates the app (inside MaterialApp widget) when the language is changed.

Comment: You could try and call `await tester.pumpAndSettle();`(perhaps even multiple times) after calling `pumpWidget()`. My tests also started to fail after adding localization to the MaterialApp. I guess it's because adding localization causes MaterialApp to have an extra render cycle.